# Cancel Gamma Correction when importing Objects

Tags: rendering, color-management

I'm having issues when importing objects from other software like Marvelous Designer.

The material color isn't the one I choose to be. I've made some research and it appears that Blender "correct" the Gamma value to be in sRGB space. Problem is I already choose my colors from a sRGB space (in Photoshop) and don't want it to be "corrected" afterwards.

[image: MD Color]

[image: Blender Color]

My question is there a way to avoid this correction when importing objects?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did find a solution to my problem. It isn't the most optimal but it will sure help, if any one have the same issue.

0 . Import your object

1. Go to the “Scene” tab
2. Go to “Color Management”

[image: https://imgur.com/sC6uXDu]

3. In “Display” change from “sRGB” to “None”

[image]

4. Go to the “Render” tab
5. Go to “Bake”

[image]

6. In “Bake Mode” change from “Full Render” to “Texture”

[image]

7. With your mesh selected go in “Edit Mode” and Unwrap your
   Object if it’s not already done. Here I use Smart UV Project to be fast.
   Then Bake and save the image result with F3 or on the menu.

[image]

8. Go back to the “Scene” tab
9. Change “None” to “sRGB”

[image]

10. Go the “Material” tab
11. Remove all material except one (doesn’t really matter which one is it)

[image]

12. Go to the “Texture” tab, add a new texture with “Image or Movie” type
13. Select your Bake result image (it’s already in Blender so you don’t have import it)

[image]

You’re done. I didn’t find anything else to avoid all that process right now. It’s fine for me because I also use the baked image as an IDmap.

Note: *On my viewport the material show the exact colors because I selected “Shadeless” in the Material proprieties.*

Hope it will help.